# Are purple cherry tomatoes ripe and if not can I pick them and will they ripen off the vine?

Tags: vegetables, tomatoes, plant-recommendations, container-gardening, ripening

I started growing my cherry tomatoes in July, but used a container rather then planting them in the ground. Most of the tomatoes have ripened. But I have a few that are not turning red, but staying purple. A few questions:

- Are they ok and just taking their time?
- Can I eat them now?
- If I pick them will they ripen off the vine?
  [image]

Comment: When fall comes, put all the unripe tomatoes in a paper bag.  Inspect once a week and toss anything that is rotting.  Some will take weeks to ripen.  You can gradually enjoy your tomatoes for a couple of months.  Re the color, try one and see if you like it; if not, let the rest ripen some more.

Comment: Great tip -thank you for this

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if you've planted a purple variety that turns red when it ripens (I plant a non-cherry variety called Blue Beauty [at least I think that's its name], which does exactly that). If so, these may not turn red due to reduced light levels (and perhaps cooler temperatures), but they'll ripen anyway. I'd either pick one now and try it and/or pick all of them and put them in the house to see if they'll "redden up" over the next few days.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not know there were purple varieties of cherry tomatoes. I knew about yellow and orange and of course red, but not purple. I am going to pick a few and monitor.

Comment: Some purple varieties are purple when ripe while others turn mostly red (often with purple shoulders). Can't really tell which your variety is, unfortunately.